# Focus pushed item in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, focus

```
<div class="comment-details">
                <input class="comment-input" ref="authorInput" type="text" v-model="item.author" />
                <textarea class="comment-input" ref="contentInput" v-model="item.content">
                </textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="add-comment" @click="addComment()">

   addComment () {
      this.newComment.author = ''
      this.newComment.content = ''
      // Add item to comments
      this.comments.push(this.newComment)
      // Set Focus To the last authorInput
      this.$refs.authorInput[this.comments.length - 1].focus()
      // Vue.nextTick(function () { this.$refs.authorInput[this.comments.length - 1].focus() })
  }
```

in VueJS Project, onClick this function return an error in console :
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined"
this.comments.length - 1 return the index of the last item (2)
this.$refs.authorInput[0].focus() => Focus the first item !

Thanks.

Comment: What's the result of uncommenting the last line and commenting the 2nd to last? (i.e., ensure you're referencing the `$refs` after `Vue.nextTick()`)

Comment: are you sure this.$refs.authorInput is an array?